# How to return/print a particular value from json using python

Tags: json, python-2.7

My function returns a string value which I have assigned to variables. I am converting it to json and I want to return the value of 'printer_id'

Code :

```
import json
def getprinterid():
    s='''
    {
    "printer_config": {
    "printer_id": "AQAAAAFhvL8CXQ",
    "conn_config_url": "https://connectivity",
    "printer_caps_url": "https://deviceconfig",
    "cred_refresh_url": "https://registration"
    }
    ,"cloud_config": {
    "eprint_enabled": true,
    "sips_enabled": true,
    "mobile_print_enabled": true
    }
    }
    '''

    decodedinfo = json.loads(s)
    for x in decodedinfo:
        if x == "printer_config":
            for y in decodedinfo[x]:
                if y == "printer_id":
                    return decodedinfo[x][y]
```

Added the curly braces , Test runs successfully now , Output:=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Thats not a JSON

Comment: You missed the opening curly brace

Comment: Added the curly braces, and now its running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoded json will be a dictionary, you can reference its keys directly:

```
import json

def getprinterid():
    s = '''
    { 
    "printer_config": {
    "printer_id": "AQAAAAFhvL8CXQ",
    "conn_config_url": "https://connectivity",
    "printer_caps_url": "https://deviceconfig",
    "cred_refresh_url": "https://registration"
    } 
    ,"cloud_config": {
    "eprint_enabled": true,
    "sips_enabled": true,
    "mobile_print_enabled": true
    } 
    } 
    '''

    decoded = json.loads(s)
    return decoded['printer_config']['printer_id']
```